# Is "Everything I should know" a phrase or a clause?

Tags: sentence-construction, parts-of-speech

Is "Everything I should know" a phrase or a clause? I think "I should know" is a dependent clause and "Everything" is a pronoun. Pronoun + dependent clause = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a noun phrase. It contains a dependent clause (a relative clause)

The word "Everything" is a pronoun. It is being described by a relative clause. In general, a noun phrase can consist of a noun or pronoun with various determiners, adjectives and relative clauses. The following are all noun phrases:

> sheep
>   white sheep
>   the white sheep
>   the white sheep that plays
>   the white sheep that plays hopscotch on the green hill